# blazor server route parameters not working

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I'm trying to do something very simple in blazor, but as simple as it seems it doesn't work for me, can someone help me what I'm doing wrong.

my route
https://localhost:44398/verificador/gdtvf
if i send ...verificador/gdtvf
I get an error, but there are no details of the error

yes send ... /verificador
load correctly.

I attach my code

.razor

```
@page "/verificador"
@page "/verificador/{ClaveId}"
<video class="d-block w-100" src="~/movie/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" muted autoplay loop>
</video>
<div class="formLogin ">
    @ClaveId
</div>
```

razor.cs

```
public partial class FrmVerificador
{
    [Parameter] public string ClaveId { get; set; }
}
```

[I get the message that something went wrong and it is necessary to reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGddJ.png)

in the browser console there is no error message, and if I have activated the error messages

app.razor

```
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
  <Found Context="routeData">
    <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(MainLayout)" />
  </Found>
  <NotFound>
      <h1>Page not found</h1>
        <p>Sorry, but there's nothing here!</p>
  </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Comment: Your URL visits /verifier/ but in your razor code you have specified it as /verificador/

Comment: so leave only @page "/verifier/{ClaveId}" the same error jumps.

Comment: What does your browser console say? Looks like your running into an exception within the page itself

Comment: The console does not say anything about an internal error, the strange thing is that I create a project from scratch, the same code works well, it is something very very rare, so I asked to see if someone had the same thing happen to him due to some error with visual, I was hoping it was a common bug with something in the Visual.

Comment: It's already solved, I lost the line
<base href="~/" />

in the _Host.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I solved it changing like this:

```html
@page "/verificador/SomeThingHere"
@page "/verificador/{ClaveId}"
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the missing first capital letter of the variable name.
I had something like:

```
@page "/verificador/{claveId}"
```

Instead of:

```
@page "/verificador/{ClaveId}"
```

And i got the exact same error...